# Bigquery : how to declare an array variable and set data with a select statement?

Tags: sql, variables, google-bigquery, declare

I am trying to declare an array variable on BigQuery but I don't manage to put a SQL statement in my variable. I couldn't find any topic about that.

I want to put in my variable all the column names of a table so I tried this :

```
DECLARE my_array ARRAY <STRING>;

SET my_array = (
  SELECT column_name
  FROM my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
);

SELECT my_array
```

I think I have a syntax problem because the error is :

```
Query error: Cannot coerce expression (
  SELECT column_name
  FROM my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
) to type ARRAY<STRING> at [3:16]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you try this one ?

```sql
DECLARE my_array ARRAY <STRING>;

SET my_array = ARRAY(
  SELECT column_name
  FROM my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
);

SELECT my_array;
```

Or, this will work also.

```sql
SET my_array = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(column_name)
  FROM my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of such a query is not an array as the declared variable, so you have to aggregate results *as an array* to match the proper type:

```sql
DECLARE something ARRAY<STRING>;

SET something = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(column_name)
  FROM my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
);

SELECT something;
```

You can find the documentation [at this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language)

Comment: It works. Thanks also for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use string array as `#1`, but you can also use approach `#2` to simply return a table with `table_name` and `column_name`.

#### # 1) Array

```
DECLARE colum_name_array ARRAY <STRING>;

SET colum_name_array = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(column_name)
  FROM `[project_id].[datset_name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  WHERE table_name = '[table_name]'
);

SELECT colum_name_array;
```

#### # 2) Table name with column names (Unnested)

```
WITH
table_columns AS (
  SELECT table_name, ARRAY_AGG(column_name) as column_name_array
  FROM `[project_id].[datset_name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  WHERE table_name = '[table_name]'
)
SELECT table_name, colum_name
FROM table_columns, UNNEST(column_name_array) as colum_name
;
```