# Assign query result to variable in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to assign the result of the select statement into a variable. For example, the result of my select statement is a list of IDs. Now I want that list to be assigned to a variable, so that I can use it in another select statement.

Like in the example below but instead of giving the actual list, I want to put the result of the select statement.

```
DECLARE ids_list ARRAY <STRING>;
SET ids_list = ['165', '148010', '50610'];
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
DECLARE ids_list ARRAY <STRING>;

SET ids_list = ARRAY(
  WITH sample_table AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS some_string UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a' AS some_string
  )
  SELECT some_string from sample_table
);

SELECT ids_list;
```

Have found the solution while playing with the code here: [Bigquery : how to declare an array variable and set data with a select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337471/bigquery-how-to-declare-an-array-variable-and-set-data-with-a-select-statement)

As another option you may use SELECT INTO statement to save your temporary results into a table:

```
SELECT * INTO my_new_table FROM my_table
```